# SFML 2.1 RenderWindow linking error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, sfml

My code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event Event; 
        while(window.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            if(Event.type == sf::Event::Closed || Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                window.close();
        }

        window.display();
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

My compiler call:

```
g++ main.cpp -framework SFML -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

The error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)", referenced from:
      _main in cc8BMfpR.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is RenderWindow in a library I forgot to link? I assumed it was in the 'window' one.. I'm running SFML 2.1 and tried various linking combinations, all of which give me linking errors. This linking chain is the one that gives me the least error, namely the RenderWindow error. Someone help me figure this out? I'm at a bit of a loss here. I'm running on mac os 10.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is RenderWindow in a library I forgot to link? I assumed it was in the 'window' one..

It's in the graphics package. Hence in sfml-graphics. But you already linked that one. However, you're not suppose to link against SFML.framework (it contains only header files).

As stated [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-osx.php), you can use either frameworks or dylibs. Your program can be compiled with either:

```
g++ main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp -framework sfml-graphics -framework sfml-window -framework sfml-system
```

Now, regarding the *Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64* error, I can only guess you didn't download the compatible version from the [download page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1/). If you want to use g++, download the "GCC" version.

Or, switch to [clang](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/clang.1.html). (E.g., you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187414/clang-vs-gcc-which-produces-better-binaries) that clang can be faster than GCC.)

Comment: I did indeed mess up and download the wrong version.. seems to be compiling fine now that the gcc version is in place except now when I try running the output I get more errors..

Comment: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE
  Referenced from: /Users/.../Work/Game_Projects/SFML_tutorials/./a.out
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE
  Referenced from:

Comment: /Users/.../Work/Game_Projects/SFML_tutorials/./a.out
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: I see you created another question for that. I'll answer there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911878/sfml-2-1-lazy-symbol-binding-failed

Comment: If this answer satisfy your question, could you accept it? :-)