# SFML 2.1 & "lazy symbol binding failed"

Tags: lazy-evaluation, sfml, symbols, dylib

I've compiled my SFML program with g++ and that seems to be working fine now (had issues with it previously), however when I try to run the resulting output, I get the following error message:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE
  Referenced from: /Users/fabricecastel/Work/Game_Projects/SFML_tutorials/./a.out
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE
  Referenced from: /Users/fabricecastel/Work/Game_Projects/SFML_tutorials/./a.out
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've checked the folder in question and libsfml-graphics.2.dylib isn't missing. Besides that I'm at a total loss as to what the issue is and how I'm supposed to fix it. Seems to me that the RenderWindow symbol isn't included in the dylib but it should be. We're talking SFML 2.1 here, not some obscure amateur project. What's up with that?

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my computer. (10.8) Are you using a custom version of GCC or the one shipped with Xcode CLT?

Comment: I've got the version shipped with Xcode :|

Comment: The version of gcc provided by Apple is soooo old... You'd better use clang/libc++ (as mentioned on your other question, there are plenty of reason to do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could reproduce these errors is when [GCC and Clang version of SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1/) are mixed. Here are two procedures that create the same errors.

- First procedure

  1. install the GCC version
  2. compile your application (successfully)
  3. install the Clang version
  4. run your application
- Second procedure

  1. install the Clang version
  2. compile your application (successfully)
  3. install the GCC version
  4. run your application

When you install another runtime, you need to carefully rebuild from scratch your application. That is, remove the final binary as well as any `.o` files before compiling.

Comment: The application is the same simple test program (open a new window, really). I deleted the output file and recompiled the program to no avail, I get the same error every time. I think there may be some issue whereby the dylib don't follow the correct version. I'll try re-installing SFML. Again. Sigh.

Comment: DAAAAMMMNNN finially worked! :D thanks a thousand times over! I cleared up all the dylib files and dropped the GCC ones back in and it works. Never mind the fact that the stuff displayed on the window is gibberish hahaha I can execute the program so that's good enough to keep me happy for now.