# Difference between GCC and Clang optimization options

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

Precondition: I invoke gcc with -O2 optimization flag and clang with -O2 optimization flag.
Does it means the options list passed to the compilers will be the same?
Do clang understand standard GCC options like -funroll-loops?

I did not find anything useful about this question in manual:
http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html
I can not even find a list of possible GCC compatible options that can be used with clang.

Do clang even do anything with GCC options (or it just ignore them?)
I just need some clarifications on how it work.

Comment: Check clang manual for that. It understands that option but I'm not sure it'll understand ALL of them.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `-O2` will mean the same in clang in gcc. Given that they have different optimizers, such a guarantee would not be possible anyway.

Comment: @Adriano The [clang manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) is surprisingly silent on what optimization options it actually supports, and their meaning.

Comment: @user4815162342 it's just an entry point for all documentation you need. For example [this list of optimization flags](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html).

Comment: @MikhailKalashnikov just read link I posted in previous comment. Manual is an entry point for other (more exhaustive) articles.

Comment: @Adriano The list doesn't document the meaning of `-O2`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user4815162342 no, list is documenting just optimizations made by compiler (and relative flags), it's what OP asked (_"Do clang understand standard GCC options like -funroll-loops?"_). If they're different or not...of course they are ([random pick here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187414/clang-vs-gcc-which-produces-better-binaries)). What each -O does? It's explained again [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels).

Comment: @Adriano The OP actually asked about the meaning of clang's `-O2` compared to gcc's. The question begins with the statement that both `gcc` and `clang` are invoked with `-O2`, which leads to the question of whether the underlying optimizations are the same, and - as a consequence - does clang even understand `-funroll-loops` and such. While it is nice that an SO answer explains what `-O2` does on `clang`, it would be better to find actual documentation. In comparison, GCC documentation pretty precisely explains what flags are turned on by optimization options `-O`, `-O2`, `-O3`, `-Os`, etc.

Comment: @user4815162342 I agree documentation lacks of that lists but it's pretty easy to find it (and link explains how). Anyway...

Answer (score 5):

Although in general Clang attempts to copy the command-line options from GCC, there are different optimization passes in GCC and LLVM, so specific optimization flags are not shared. In particular, it means that `-O2` does not behave the same in the two compilers.

If you want to see the list of optimizations that GCC applies under `-O2`, check [its documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html); if you want to see the list Clang applies, check [this related Stackoverflow question about how to see the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels).