# Why are there duplicate C/C++ compilers (e.g g++, gcc)?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/172592/19580246), `gcc` and `g++` have some functional differences. As confirmed by this script, the commands point to the exact same binary, effectively making them duplicates. Why is that so?

```bash
$ uname
Darwin
$ md5 `which cc c++ gcc g++ clang clang++`
fac4668657765c8dfe89d8995acfb5a2  /usr/bin/cc
fac4668657765c8dfe89d8995acfb5a2  /usr/bin/c++
fac4668657765c8dfe89d8995acfb5a2  /usr/bin/gcc
fac4668657765c8dfe89d8995acfb5a2  /usr/bin/g++
fac4668657765c8dfe89d8995acfb5a2  /usr/bin/clang
fac4668657765c8dfe89d8995acfb5a2  /usr/bin/clang++
```

Comment: Do you know what `argv[0]` parameter is, to `main`? Have you considered the possibility of using `argv[0]` to control the program's behavior?

Comment: Ever been to a restaurant that serves both Mexican and Texan food? Now imagine they have a Mexican and a Texan menu. That's gcc and g++.

Comment: Linking `gcc` to the `clang` executable seems very misleading.

Comment: @interjay that's what Apple has did for years, probably since 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable can determine the name it was called with by inspecting the first (or zeroth) command line argument passed to it. By convention it is the name of the executable and is passed by whatever program is invoking the compiler (typically e.g. a shell).

Although it is the same executable, it can then take different actions based on whether or not that value is `gcc` or `g++`.

Also, the files you are seeing are unlikely to be duplicate files. They are most likely just (soft or hard) links to the same file.

---

For the part that `clang`/`clang++` and `gcc`/`g++` seem to be the same, although they are completely different compilers, that is an Apple quirk. They link `gcc` and `g++` to `clang` and `clang++` for some reason, but in reality both refer to Apple clang, which is also different from upstream clang. It often causes confusion (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

> the commands point to the exact same binary, effectively making them duplicates

Yes, they're intended to be the same, and are actually the same single file on disk, given the inode number of them is the same

```
$ which cc c++ gcc g++ clang clang++ | xargs ls -li
1152921500312779808 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167120 May 10 04:30 /usr/bin/c++
1152921500312779808 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167120 May 10 04:30 /usr/bin/cc
1152921500312779808 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167120 May 10 04:30 /usr/bin/clang
1152921500312779808 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167120 May 10 04:30 /usr/bin/clang++
1152921500312779808 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167120 May 10 04:30 /usr/bin/g++
1152921500312779808 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167120 May 10 04:30 /usr/bin/gcc
```

On a typical *nix system symlinks are usually used instead of hard links like that

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin | grep 'vim'
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         3 May 10 04:30 ex -> vim
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         3 May 10 04:30 rview -> vim
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         3 May 10 04:30 rvim -> vim
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         3 May 10 04:30 vi -> vim
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         3 May 10 04:30 view -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel   5056496 May 10 04:30 vim
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel         3 May 10 04:30 vimdiff -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel      2154 May 10 04:30 vimtutor
```

That said, in any case the command can be determined easily, regardless of the full executable file, a hard link or a symlink, by checking the command executed which is `argv[0]` in a typical C or C++ program, or `$0` in bash. This is extremely common and one notable usage of it is in [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) where almost all POSIX utilities are in a single `busybox` binary and anything you run like `ls`, `mv`, `test`, `rm`... will eventually run `busybox`

---

But why is gcc and clang the same binary? It's another weird thing in macOS because Apple stopped using/including gcc for more than a decade ago due to licensing issues. They lie to others by telling "clang is gcc" and the only way you can know it is by running `gcc --version`

- [OS X: installed gcc links to clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40034457/995714)
- [What is the difference between c++ and g++ on Mac OS X (CommandLineTools)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54190340/995714)
- [How do I make sure that my default C/C++ compiler is GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61292460/995714)
- [OS X 10.9 gcc links to clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19535422/995714)

Comment: how come `readlink $(…)` fails, though?

Comment: @pacificocean fail for what? the compilers above are hard links so obviously `readlink` won't work. But for real symlinks like `/usr/bin/vimdiff` then it'll work